# C# Appium IsAppInstalled error: Could not find package

Tags: c#, android, appium

**The problem**

Hello.

I have a class in C# to verify if my app is installed or not in my device.

When my device has the app installed, everything works fine. However, when my device does not have the app installed, the system gives me this error message:

Message:

> Test method MYAPP.Main.RunTest.RunAllTests threw exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find
>   package com.android.MyApp on the device

How to use and declare the IsAppInstalled?

I’m using VS 2017 Community.

**Environment**

- Appium version (or git revision) that exhibits the issue: Appium
  Driver v4.0.30319
- Last Appium version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable):
  Same
- Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: Windows 10 Pro
- Node.js version (unless using Appium.app|exe): Node.js v10.1.0
- Mobile platform/version under test: Android 8.0
- Real device or emulator/simulator: Real device Samsung S9
- Appium CLI or Appium.app|exe: Appium Server v1.8.0

**Details**

```
My Capabilities:

public class CapDeviceConfig{

    public DesiredCapabilities CapDeviceConfigOptions(){
        //set the capabilities (https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md)

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.SetCapability("automationName", "Appium"); // Which automation engine to use
        cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android"); // Which mobile OS platform to use
        cap.SetCapability("platformVersion", "8.0.0"); // Mobile OS version
        cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "starlte"); // The kind of mobile device or emulator to use // S9
        cap.SetCapability("udid", "2270048324037ece"); // Unique device identifier of the connected physical device
        cap.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.android.MyApp");
        cap.SetCapability("appActivity", "md5ab6683a3e3c3f0bd6864e3305b4e45c6.SplashScreenActivity");    
        cap.SetCapability("noReset", "True"); // Don't reset app state before this session.
        cap.SetCapability("printPageSourceOnFindFailure", "True"); // When a find operation fails, print the current page source.
        return cap;
    }
}
```

**Link to Appium logs**

https://gist.github.com/pbmzbr/b0638a0237c7d846de2e94000163c1f6

**Code To Reproduce Issue**

```
public class AppInstallVerification{

            //Creating instance for Appium driver
            AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> driverCheck;

            CapDeviceConfig cap = new CapDeviceConfig();

            EnrollmentTests enrollmentTests = new EnrollmentTests();

            InstallApp install = new InstallApp();

            public void IsAppInstalled(){

                cap.CapDeviceConfigOptions();
                driverCheck = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap.CapDeviceConfigOptions());

                if (driverCheck.IsAppInstalled("com.android.MyApp"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("App is installed!");
                    enrollmentTests.CodeApplied();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("App is not installed!");
                    install.InstallingApp();
                }            
            }
        }
```